# How to arrange the items correctly in flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to make design of page of display comment. I need make page design is as follows: list at up and then Text Field at the bottom.So user will can see all comment and send new comment.
Something like photo:

[image]

but I have same problem with display.

This is my code:I make it like that now but now I can see list just without text field at the bottom

```
  @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return FutureBuilder<List<Flowerdata>>(
        future: fetchFlowers(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {

          if (!snapshot.hasData) return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator()
          );

          return ListView(

            children: snapshot.data
                .map((data) => Column(children: <Widget>[

              GestureDetector(
                onTap: ()=>{
                  getItemAndNavigate(data.id, context)
                },
                child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          width: 100,
                          height: 100,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                              child:
                              Image.network(data.flowerImageURL,
                                width: 200, height: 100, fit: BoxFit.cover,))),

                      Flexible(child:
                      Text(data.flowerName,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18))
                      ),

                    ]),),

              Divider(color: Colors.black),

            ],))
                .toList(),

          );

          Container(
              width: 280,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: TextField(
                controller: naameController,
                autocorrect: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Your Name Here'),
              )
          );

        },

      );

  }
```

How can I arrange the items correctly?

Comment: This may be because list take all the height and no space left for textfields.Try to make list scrollable and check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your `Container` widget is unreachable, you should fix it then you can wrap your widgets with `Column` and wrap `ListView` with `Expanded` widget after giving `height` to `Container`. It will fix your problem.

But i have some suggestions about `ListView`. Why you did not use `ListView.separated`? If you use `separated` method you can delete `map` and your `Divider`.

Also when i looked your design, your list items looks like a card. You can use `Card` widget beside of `GestureDetector`.

I hope this will help you, if not i will glad to help you.

Edit: Here is sample code based on your question and my answer;

```
  Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
            InkWell(
              onTap: () => getItemAndNavigate(snapshot.data[i].id, context),
              child: Card(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                        child: Image.network(snapshot.data[i].flowerImageURL,
                            width: 200, height: 100, fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Text(
                        snapshot.data[i].flowerName,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: 280,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: TextField(
          autocorrect: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Your Name Here'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Hello, brother. Thanks for your answer first. I tried to apply what you mentioned to me but it didn't work, sorry but I am a new filter developer

Comment: No problem, i edited my answer with sample code to understand.

Comment: @Mafo if my answer worked, please mark my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, brother. Thank you the problem has been resolved. Always wish to you good luck

Answer (score 0):

You are placing the TextField in the position after returning ListView, which make it dead code. You can add it at the end of your ListView children list or place a Stack outside to place both the ListView and TextField inside.

Comment: Hi Bach, welcome to StackOverflow.

Stack can be solution but using Column and Expanded widgets is easier solution i think.